# python multiprocessing: call function from main process?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I need to call function from subprocess, but I don't know how to do it right.
My code:

```
def GzipSend(pth):
    path, filename = os.path.split(pth)
    day0 = os.path.join(pth, 'daily.0')
    if os.path.exists(day0):
        try:
            tar = Popen("tar cPf - %s" %day0, shell=True, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
            pigz = Popen("pigz -1 -kc", stdin=tar.stdout, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
            send = Popen("./s3cmd -c ./.s3cfg sync - s3://%s/%s/daily.0.tar.gz" %(bucket_name,filename), stdin=pigz.stdout, shell=True, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
            tar.stdout.close()
            pigz.stdout.close()
            out, err = send.communicate()
            tar.wait()
            pigz.wait()
            return True
        except Exception, e:
            return False
    else:
        return False

def log(result, pth=None):
    if result:
        logger.info('path %s SUCCESS', pth)
    else:
        logger.info('path %s ERROR', pth) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    all = []
    for i in SubDirPath(work_path):
            all.append(i)
    p = mp.Pool(processes=workers_num)
    for pth in all:
        p.apply_async(GzipSend, args=(pth, ), callback=partial(log, pth=pth))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

I want to add function  "if os.path.exists(day0)" false.
My question: where do I need to create a function - on the main process or on the subprocess?

I want something like this:

```
 def GzipSend(pth):
    if:
        try:
            def func(param1)
        except
    else:
        def func(param2)

def log(result, pth=None):
....

if __name__ == '__main__':
...
```

Comment: Can you clarify what function you want to add?

Comment: I want to make a separate function all that is between "try" "except"

Comment: I edit my question.
Where do I need to put my function def func() to the "if __name__ == '__main__': " code block or not?